# Identifying an Unknown Blood Type

Tags: human-biology, hematology, red-blood-cell, blood-group

> The following case study has a student working with blood samples to
>   identify their blood types (A, B, AB, and O). Consider the situation
>   and answer the questions.
>
> A student is given eight red blood cell suspensions, which contain
>   only red blood cells, and the matching serum from each sample. (Serum
>   is blood plasma in which fibrinogen has been removed.)
>
> She is asked to identify each of the four different blood types
>   present. To test these samples, the only materials she has at her
>   disposal are a sample of type A red cell suspension and the serum from
>   type A blood.
>
> Describe the step-by-step procedure that she must use to identify the
>   four different blood types present. In each step, interpret what it
>   means if the cells in the sample clump together, or if they do not
>   clump together.

I am mostly confused on what exactly "she has at her disposal are a sample of type A red cell suspension and the serum from type A blood." means..? What is a A red cell suspension?

**I already know that:**

TYPE A: has anti-B antibodies

TYPE B: has anti-A antibodies

TYPE AB: has neither anti-A nor anti B antibodies

TYPE O: has both anti-A and anti-B antibodies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The passage:

> To test these samples, the only materials she has at her disposal are
>   a sample of type A red cell suspension and the serum from type A
>   blood.

means, I take it, that she has available two containers: One has red blood cells from a known blood-type A individual suspended in a neutral fluid such as saline solution.  The other container has blood plasma (without red blood cells or fibrinogen) also from a known blood-type A individual.

These should be enough to determine the blood types of four individuals  from the unknown test tubes (four pairs of test tubes, each pair being one with cell suspensions and one with plasma, coming from four individuals having different blood types).